# Sorry for Posting Yet Another Why Was this Question Closed Post?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

I really do not understand how a practical and very real question regarding use of one of the commonest text editors used by programmers be off topic on a programmers Q&A forum?

[Battling Emacs Pinky?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/178621/battling-emacs-pinky)

Comment: did you check [site FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)? "site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development. If you have a question about..." etc

Comment: I didn't understand your question to be about the editor, it seemed to be how to get used to working on different keyboards, just in the context of using Emacs. In my opinion, it didn't fit the scope of the site.

Comment: I agree with Tim, I read it as a question about working with different keyboards that could apply to any person in any profession and thus off-topic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why was my comment deleted? I was trying to point out that this isn't a site about Programmers, despite the site's name. It's a site about Conceptual Software Development. It sounds like haziz thinks this is a site about programmers based on his question.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange sites solve a problem that other platforms don't. They're not discussion forums; instead, they're highly targeted, laser-focused questions and answers sites. Programmers SE is about solving whiteboard problems in software development.

As gnat says, the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) defines the list of topics that [Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) supports as well as topics that are explicitly off-topic.

From the FAQ:

> Please make sure your question uniquely applies to programmers in general:

A question about how to use keyboards on different computers is not unique to the programming profession. Anyone who owns both a Mac and a PC may very well face this problem; thus, it's not a good fit for a site about whiteboard problems in software development. It doesn't make it a bad question; it just means it's not a good fit for *this* SE site.

There may be a site for your question, but it's not here. Please see the [List of Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) and the various FAQs to see if any would welcome questions about keyboards. I'd suggest starting with [Super User's FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) first. Hope this helps!

Comment: There are other professions that use emacs?